# Privacy fence to gate issues

Tags: fence

[image]how do I straighten my my gate attached to the neighbors privacy fence?? I can not open the fence due to the leaning into my yard, it was working great before winter hit

Comment: We just moved in, in October 2018, the leaning has worsened in the last couple weeks, I can’t find a suitable jack to use between my house and the post, also don’t want to damage the wall of my house any suggestions would be great thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a brace from the foundation to the top left corner of your fence with a jack - foundation won't move and use a thick plank to spread the load either end...

Comment: after looking closer to the left side of the gate at the fence post, I would have to do this on the opposite side as the gate opens inward, (towards the taken pic) but there is not much of the post on the opposite side, I may have to use the rail and post for structural strength, but from the fence I am having to push it back to the left 5 inches in order for the gate to latch as designed

Answer (score 1):

I know you have chosen a "correct" answer but i do not think it is a proper solution.

It appears that both posts are moving as the ground freeze's and thaw's. If they are doing so now they will continue to do so in the future, regardless of bracing.

***You will need to call for utility locates so you do not dig into a gas line or other utilities.***

I would dissemble and **start over**. I would install two new posts,  the one the fence side i would put about 18" in from the fence since you have room on the house side. You need to set the new posts at least to what frost line code calls for in you area but i would try to go as deep as you can. If the frost line is 48" then try to go at least 60". If your ground is particularly active you may want to use sono tubes and fill with concrete and even put a bell footer on your sono tubes.